# how to get jquery mobile + Isotope.js to work together

Tags: jquery-mobile, jquery-isotope

Does anyone have any examples/suggestions for making jquery mobile play nicely with Isotope.js?

Many Thanks,

R

Comment: What is play nicely? You need to give much more info and any code you have tried.

Comment: Here is a demo in JQM -- http://jsfiddle.net/vqoavpqu/ -- taken from http://codepen.io/desandro/pen/nFrte. so you can see JQM's css needs adjusting but its playing very nice